# IOS Autolayout change anchorPoint of view and rotate scale

Tags: ios, autolayout, anchor, constraints, transform

if I set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints YES,  I change the view's layer anchorPoint, the console print :
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.

```
CGPoint anchor=CGPointMake((self.scrollview.frame.size.width/2+self.scrollview.contentOffset.x)/self.imageview.frame.size.width, (self.scrollview.frame.size.height/2+self.scrollview.contentOffset.y)/self.imageview.frame.size.height);
self.imageview.layer.anchorPoint=anchor;
self.imageview.layer.position=CGPointMake(self.scrollview.frame.size.width/2+self.scrollview.contentOffset.x, self.scrollview.frame.size.height/2+self.scrollview.contentOffset.y);
CGAffineTransform  transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((slider.value*100/180));
self.imageview.layer.transform=CATransform3DMakeAffineTransform(transform);
```

the code like this. I can't use it to let imageview  rotate around a point。

> I have another question. when I use auto layout , I can't change frame directly. I must change constraint. whether I can't animate my view use old code ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

1. After you adopt auto layout, you should **always** modify constraints instead frame. You cannot animate your view with old frame modified code.
2. My recommendation is always set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO` and set up your constraint through code or xib.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have made some test for the constraint. I think many third-part libs on github isn't useful for constraint. I decide to write my project with old style.

Comment: And how do you modify the `anchorPoint` through constraints?!